# difficulty in extracting only a part of URL

Tags: r, regex

I have stored a URL link in a vector as :

```
 links <- "https://www.amazon.in/Glass-Milk-Bottle-Clear-Pieces/dp/B01J9SKYYU&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiGkd_x8P3ZAhUOSY8KHZUVBg0QFggmMAA&usg=AOvVaw1wAFHoDLiP94xbl9JJsp8E"
```

And I wanted to extract only one part of the above url:
i.e. "https://www.amazon.in/Glass-Milk-Bottle-Clear-Pieces/dp/B01J9SKYYU"

What I am trying to do is in the below code but I could not do that..

```
 library(stringr)
 upattern <- "http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\\(\\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+"
 ExtractedURL <- str_extract(links[1], upattern)
```

Where I did make the mistake?

Comment: `sub("&.*", "", links)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Ohh it was that simple... thanks